# Basic Help For Html Tables

Tags: html, css, tabular

```css
table > thead > tr >th>.empty-cell{
  background-color: transparent ;
  border : none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head><title>Table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
    <body>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class="empty-cell"></th>
    <th> Smart Starter </th>
    <th> Smart Medium </th>
    <th> Smart Business </th>
    <th> Smart Deluxe </th>

</thead>
<tbody>
</tr>


</table>

</body>
```

I want to have a empty cell in header table in css like this pic:

[image: table]

Can anyone help me? I'm a very beginner.

Comment: where is the issue? for an empty cell just use an empty cell `<td></td>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have not noticed the empty cell in the first line because of no content in any other cell in the first column below. I have moved a misplaced `</tr>` and made a bit of order in the style:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Table</title>
<style>
table{
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 5px;
}
th,td.greenc{
  background-color: #0c0;
}
th.empty{
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="empty"></th>
      <th> Smart Starter </th>
      <th> Smart Medium </th>
      <th> Smart Business </th>
      <th> Smart Deluxe </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="greenc"> Storage Space </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="greenc"> B </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="greenc"> C </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="greenc"> D </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="greenc"> E </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="greenc"> F </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Check the updated snippet:

```css
table{
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 5px;
}
th,td.greenc{
  background-color: #0c0;
}
th.empty{
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="empty"></th>
      <th> Smart Starter </th>
      <th> Smart Medium </th>
      <th> Smart Business </th>
      <th> Smart Deluxe </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="greenc"> Storage Space </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="greenc"> B </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="greenc"> C </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="greenc"> D </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
      <td> Content </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="greenc"> E </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="greenc"> F </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
      <td> &#10003; </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can further customize the style as you prefer. We couldn't see your `style.css` file before answering: always remember that CSS is **cascade** style sheet.

Comment: thank u brother. i wanna exactly like this pic in size ,font and table.just i wanna use purple and orchid color instead of green and lite green. and i wanna that ticks.and the bottom row. can you please write it full?html &css file.and i voted thank you again bro :)

Comment: @RezaGhash I updated markup and style, now you can update on your own the content of the cells and some custom styles like borders, colors or round corners :)

Comment: bro thank you.but this isnt that thing i want.may you write "price per month" row and make table width 100% for me? i a cant change the colors,please change td color and storage space til "F"  to purple and rest of cells to orchid.and please make text color white. can you bro?im so sorry

Comment: i forgot about cells size. i want it big just like pic. and can you put html and css file in a zip file and send for me?thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

This is an exemple without Bootstrap, i used font-awesome for icon, look the complete code here https://codepen.io/alex-grz/pen/KKNZvOZ.

```css
table {
   font-family: sans-serif;
}
.table>tbody>tr>td, 
.table>tbody>tr>th, 
.table>tfoot>tr>td, 
.table>tfoot>tr>th, 
.table>thead>tr>td, 
.table>thead>tr>th {
  text-align:center;
   padding:1rem 3rem;
   font-size: .8rem;
}

.table > thead > tr > th:first-child {
  background-color:unset;
}

.table > thead > tr > th {
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0; 
}

.table > tbody > tr > th { 
  border-radius: 6px 0 0px 6px;
}

.table > thead > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > th  {
  background-color:#9BD727;
  color:white; 
}

.table > tbody > tr > td {
   background-color:#DEF2CC;
  color:black;
}

.table>tfoot>tr>td {
  color: #9BD727;
  font-size:1rem;
}

.fa-check {
  color:#9BD727;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  
<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">Smart Starter</th>
        <th scope="col">Smart Medium</th>
        <th scope="col">Smart Buisiness</th>
        <th scope="col">Smart Deluxe</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Storage Space</th>
        <td>512 MB</td>
        <td>1 GB</td>
        <td>2 GB</td>
        <td>4 GB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Bandiwdth</th>
        <td>50 GB</td>
        <td>100 GB</td>
        <td>150 GB</td>
        <td>Unlimited</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">MySQL Databases</th>
        <td>Unlimited</td>
        <td>Unlimited</td>
        <td>Unlimited</td>
        <td>Unlimited</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Setup</th>
        <td>19.90 $</td>
        <td>12.90 $</td>
        <td>free</td>
        <td>free</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">PHP 5</th>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Ruby on Rails</th>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Price per month</th>
          <td>$ 2.90</td>
          <td>$ 5.90</td>
          <td>$ 9.90</td>
          <td>$ 14.90</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </tbody>
    
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i will give you example using boostrap css

```css
table > thead > tr > th.empty-cell{
  background-color: transparent ;
  border : none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="padding: 20px;">
     <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="empty-cell"></th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
              </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

i add class `empty-cell` to `<th>` like image example , and add to style `background-color: transparent ;` to make the cell like nothing, if your css table have a border you can add `border: none` to style to, its depend on you style table

Comment: maybe you need to add your sample code at your question

Comment: this is my html   <html>
 <head><title>Table</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
 <body>
<table>
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th class="empty-cell"></th>
 <th> Smart Starter </th>
 <th> Smart Medium </th>
 <th> Smart Business </th>
 <th> Smart Deluxe </th>

</thead>
<tbody>
</tr>


</table>



</body>

and css  : table > thead > tr >th>.empty-cell{
  background-color: transparent ;
  border : none;
}

Comment: just write your code at your question, and include to your css for table from style.css

Comment: i did it in question

Comment: you have any css for your table or only blank like that ?

Comment: i got more css. like text color

Comment: change your `table > thead > tr >th>.empty-cell{}` to `table > thead > tr >th.empty-cell{}` and you need write `</tr>` before `</thead>`